# How can i write a never ending job in Rails (Web Scraping)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, sidekiq

**Goal**: I want to make a web scraper in a Rails app that runs indefinitely and can be scaled.

**Current stack app is running on:**
ROR/Heroku/Redis/Postgres

**Idea**:
I was thinking of running a [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) Job that runs every *n*  minutes and checks if there are any proxies available to scrape with (these will be stored in a table with status sleeping/scraping).

Assuming there is a proxy available to scrape it will then check (using [Sidekiq API](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API)) if there is any available workers to start up another job to scrape with the available proxy.

This means i could scale the scraper by increasing number of workers and the number of available proxies. If for any reason the Job fails the Job that looks for available proxies will just start it again.

**Questions**: Is this the best solution for my goal? Is utilizing long running Sidekiq jobs the best idea or could this blow up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sidekiq is designed to run individual jobs which are "units of work" to your organization.

You can build your own loop and, inside that loop, create jobs for each page to scrape but the loop itself should not be a job.

Comment: Would there be any downsides to a long running jobs on Sidekiq? I thought about doing it like you said but then i would be filling up the queue with a ton of small jobs, and even if i prioritize other jobs over the small scraping jobs it can still cause a bottleneck for other items in the queue right?

Comment: I think i am going to take your approach, i can make the loop run in a rake task and just make the single page scrapes which will run really fast and it should bottleneck my other processes. Initially i didn't think i could scrape the pages individually given what i was trying to scrape but this should actually work perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sidekiq can scale to thousands of jobs per second, by starting more worker processes. Only you can judge if this is sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a job to run every *n* minutes, you could schedule it.

And since you're using Heroku, there is an Add-on that : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

Another solution would be to set cron jobs and schedule them with the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem.